# How to retain only first occurrence of duplicates in a row?

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a way to identify and replace row-wise duplicate values in a `data.table` with `NA`.

The following answer helps me identify row-wise duplicates...

[Removing duplicate values row-wise in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827308/removing-duplicate-values-row-wise-in-r)

...but I am looking for a way to address those duplicates.

PROBLEM

```
(dt <- data.table(X = 1:10, Y = seq(1, 19, by = 2), Z = c(1, rep(3, 9))))
```

```
     X  Y Z
 1:  1  1 1
 2:  2  3 3
 3:  3  5 3
 4:  4  7 3
 5:  5  9 3
 6:  6 11 3
 7:  7 13 3
 8:  8 15 3
 9:  9 17 3
10: 10 19 3
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
     X   Y  Z
 1:  1  NA NA
 2:  2   3 NA
 3:  3   5 NA
 4:  4   7  3
 5:  5   9  3
 6:  6  11  3
 7:  7  13  3
 8:  8  15  3
 9:  9  17  3
10: 10  19  3
```

Please help

Comment: Reshape to long format. Then this becomes easy (and efficient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
dt[, row := .I
   ][, melt(.SD, id.cols = "row", measure.vars = c("X", "Y", "Z"))
     ][, value := replace(value, duplicated(value), NA), by = row
       ][, dcast(.SD, row ~ variable)
         ][, !"row"]
```

Comment: @Ronald's comments have made me consider this answer.
@sindri_baldur: could you modify this to not have the `row` column in the final output?

Comment: thanks @sindhi_baldur 
One last thing. Anything I can do to retain an ID column? For instance, a data.table like the following:
`(dt <- data.table(ID = LETTERS[1:10], X = 1:10, Y = seq(1, 19, by = 2), Z = c(1, rep(3, 9))))
`

Comment: @SanjidRahman `dt[, row := .I ][, melt(.SD, id.cols = c("ID", "row"), measure.vars = c("X", "Y", "Z")) ][, value := replace(value, duplicated(value), NA), by = row ][, dcast(.SD, ID + row ~ variable) ][, !"row"]`

Answer (score 3):

An even shorter version of what basically is @akrun 's answer:

```
dt[t(apply(dt, 1, duplicated))] <- NA
```

Comment: This is terribly inefficient.

Comment: @Roland please elaborate or provide a more efficient solution if you have any. Do take in mind that the OP asked for a working solution, and didn't specify the size of the dataset. Nor did they ask for a solution aimed at very large datasets.

Comment: `apply` deep-copies the whole dataset. The correct data.table way is already shown in the answer by sindri_baldur.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `base R`

```
setDF(dt)
dt[] <- t(apply(dt, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))
```